# POST request with big payload is very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, http, post

I'm sending POST  request with whole html page in the payload. The request is very slow, How can I make it faster?

Comment: How big is the payload?  Is there an image or file in there somewhere or just text?

Comment: The payload is an html page (text)

Comment: Hard to see how that is causing the slowness.  File uploads are usually the larger part of a post request.  Can you post the log file results of the request?